# I can't increase window size in Visual Studio Designer because of Limited Screen Resolution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Visual Studio Experts.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOpD5.png)
Why is it, that in the Visual Studio WinForms designer I cannot increase the size of my Form above the resolution of the screen I am currently working on? I think it should somehow be possible to develop an application aimed at higher resolutions on a lower res system. The fact that this would clip the Form during debugging should not be an issue. Is there perhaps some setting in Visual Studio for this, which I cannot seem to find?

EDIT: My main issue is that I need to be able to design a (for example) 1440x900 sized form on a laptop with a (for example) 1360x768 screen.

Comment: Have you tried setting the width and height properties via the properties window?

Comment: Plus usually you'd design the form with resizing in mind, the form should have a minimum size if required, but should be able to size itself dynamically to fit whichever screen size the user has.

Comment: It is a rock-hard limitation built in the Form class with no workaround.  A large screen surely has a higher DPI setting, so it is going to grow anyway.  125% would be a typical choice, so you should design for 1152 x 720.  Designing and coding so it is arbitrarily resizable, as a window should be, is always best.